# Enthought: no Python documentation found for 'modules' + version number

Tags: python, python-module, enthought

I want to be able to list the installed modules and their version number on my Python Enthought distribution. When I open the terminal and type

```
$ help('modules')
```

i get

```
>> no Python documentation found for 'modules'
```

if I do the same for my standard python distro on the mac (/usr/bin/python/) it works fine although I am still missing the module version.

Any idea how to properly list all the installed modules and their corresponding version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all modules:

```
import sys
print sys.modules
```

for the version information ... that's a bit tricky. Because if this information is not provided by the respective package/module you relay on the underlying packaging mechanism.

if you use pip you could do a pip show or freeze or you could use [yolk](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk).

Comment: Great! pip freeze is what I was looking for. Installed pip and tried and works great.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the `enpkg` command.  Running

`enpkg -l`

from the command line will list all packages installed in EPD with version information.

Here is more info on enpkg: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22415022-using-enpkg-to-update-epd-packages

**Update:**

Regarding help('modules') itself:  It was deliberately disabled in Enthought's Python because it reliably caused segfaults with a standard set of EPD packages (among other reasons).